# How to make a Codable class with multiple possible enum types?

Tags: swift, enums, codable

Suppose I have an object which can have one of several kinds of enums. How can I make this conform to Codable?

```
protocol Status : Codable {}
enum StatusA : String, Status {
    case a = "a"
    case b = "b"
}
enum StatusB : String, Status {
    case x = "x"
    case y = "y"
}
class ProdEvent : Codable {
    let status : Status // doesn't conform to codable
}
class MyCollection : Codable {
    let arr_events : [ProdEvent] // will be unhappy if you try to use generics or associatedType
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the `Status` type generic so that compiler knows you will pass a concrete type that conforms to protocol `Status` so it is decodable & encodable.

```
class ProdEvent<T: Status> : Codable {
    let status : T
}

class MyCollection<T: Status> : Codable {
    let arr_events : [ProdEvent<T>]
}
```

Now, you can make `ProdEvent` and `MyCollection` object of any kind of `Status` type as below,

```
var aEvent: ProdEvent<StatusA>!
var bEvent: ProdEvent<StatusB>!

var aCollection: MyCollection<StatusA>!
var bCollection: MyCollection<StatusB>!
```

You can check this [thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/using-protocol-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-protocol-protocol-is-not-supported/14948) as well on why you can't use protocol as a concrete type.

Comment: This answers the question, but I left out a detail that I should have included: I would like for a collection to contain ProdEvent objects with different types of Status. I don't think it's possible with this pattern, however.